# reading 500 MB xlsx file with OpenXML in aspnet core 2.1 is giving stream is too large

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

Reading 500 MB xlsx file with OpenXML in aspnet core 2.1 is giving stream is too large.

is it any other way to read 1 gb excl file in openXML

**below is my code**

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(importExport.FileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
        Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        ....
    }
}
```

**i am getting below error**
[image]

Comment: Show us full error message and code

Comment: stack trace is:
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipWrappingStream.CopyStream(Stream source, Stream target)
   at System.IO.Packaging.ZipWrappingStream.get_Length()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart.LoadDomTree[T]()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorksheetPart.get_Worksheet()

and again it is saying stream is too large